# How to deserialize this object from json to string?

Tags: json, vb.net

I am trying to deserialize this object from json to string but it doesnt work.

`[\"661253BF9FE5463D968AC4CF9179FC56\"]` -- this is the object.

```
 Dim idDes As String = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(id)
```

I want it like this: `"661253BF9FE5463D968AC4CF9179FC56"`

Any help?

Comment: What does 'it doesn't work' mean? At a guess the exception would be that you're deserializing an array from JSON into a string. Try deserializing to a string array and then getting the first element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your JSON is telling you is that it's an array of strings, that's what you need to deserialize and if you always know you want the first string in that array you can access like this:

```
Dim idDes As String
Dim arr As String() = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of String())(json)
idDes = arr.First()
```